# How can I limit my response to a API request?

Tags: api, limit

I'm working with  [Football API](https://sportmonks.com) and I can't seem to limit my response. 
This is my request to the API: 
https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/seasons/6397?api_token=MYTOKEN&include=fixtures:limit(5/1)

I want to limit this, because the response I'm getting is to0 big.

The documentation about this endpoint: https://sportmonks.com/docs/football/2.0/seasons/a/get-by-id/9

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this one on SportMonks. Looks like they updated the Football API docs. Just add `&per_page=50`to your request for example and it'll limit the paginated response to 50 results.